# getFont not working on Android O

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, custom-font, android-fonts

I am using below code to load custom font file from res/font folder. It is working fine on devices below Android O but not loading font on Android O devices. Here is the code I am using.

```
var typeface: Typeface
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        typeface = resources.getFont(R.font.carterone)
    } else {
        typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.carterone)!!
    }
    txtview.typeface = typeface
```

What are the changes needed in this code to work on all Versions? Please help.

Comment: The `ResourcesCompat` version should work on all versions.

Comment: But nothing is working at all, i have updated my device to oreo and thats when problem starts